# SpringBatch in SystemExiter()

Tags: java, spring-batch-admin

I am studying about SpringBatch CommandLineJobRunner. I want to run Multiple Jobs from single job. Here is my code. My code is ok but I do not undersand if   **CommandLineJobRunner.presetSystemExiter( new SystemExiter()**  do not include it run only 1 job and cannot available multiple job. So please explain me how this work.

```
 CommandLineJobRunner.presetSystemExiter( new SystemExiter() 
                  { 
                        public void exit( int status ) 
                        {
                    }
                  });

  String[] params1 = { jobConfig1, jobID1, "runId=" + new Date().getTime() };
  CommandLineJobRunner.main(params1);

  String[] params2 = { jobConfig2, jobID2, "runId=" + new Date().getTime() };
  CommandLineJobRunner.main(params2);
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short : the default exiter simply calls the JVM System.exit(), which terminates your JVM.

Explained in more detail here :
http://www.dotkam.com/2011/03/15/spring-batch-commandlinejobrunner-to-run-multiple-jobs/